# What is "-Ls 1000" in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been working with inventory spreadsheets in Google Sheets. I have many SKU's in my inventory and when pasting or typing them in, they are interpreted as text and are left justified in general format cells. For example, `CF-55B`, `BB-32`, `JR-3039`.

But when I type the SKU `LS-1000` or `LS-1001`, it gets reinterpreted as **-Ls 1000** or **-Ls 1001**, both of which are right aligned and appear to be interpreted as numbers representing `-1000` and `-1001`.

Re-entering the values in as `'LS-1000` forces it to be entered as text, but can anybody tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entry is being interpreted as a Latvian currency value.

Would not happen if you switched to new Google Sheets. Meanwhile your solution is about as good as it gets.

-1,000 Lats puts you out of pocket by around USD1,800 ;-)

Comment: That was the only SKU that was getting treated that way. After discovering all the other currency formats on the format submenu, yes, of course. Rs.-1000 does the same thing, as well as a bunch of others. Of course, I wouldn't probably ever look at that submenu. Mystery solved, and thank you.